# Azure pipeline pull docker image from ACR (azure container registry) authentication required

Tags: azure, docker, pipeline, pull

I created a docker image and pushed it to my azure container registry.

Now I would like to perform the pipeline steps inside a container created with that docker image but I get this error message:

`Error response from daemon: Head "https://my_docker_registry.azurecr.io/v2/test_image/manifests/1": unauthorized: authentication required, visit https://aka.ms/acr/authorization for more information`

`##[warning]Docker pull failed with exit code 1, back off 6.501 seconds before retry.`

where am i wrong?

this is my azure-pipeline.yml:

````
trigger:
- main


resources:
  containers:
  - container: firstpipeline
    type: ACR
    azureSubscription: 814dfd24-6f11-4r4c-ae2r-ag6ke91231g2
    resourceGroup: resource_group_1
    registry: my_docker_registry.azurecr.io
    repository: test_image:1



pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
  - script: |
      cat /etc/os-release
    displayName: 'execute inside docker container' ```
````

Comment: `azureSubscription` is the service connection name, not the subscription ID. It can be confusing. See [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/service-endpoints?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#azure-repos)